# Email multiple people individual attachments

Tags: powershell, email, authentication, attachment

I am using Send-MailMessage to email multiple different recipients each with an individual report. I have just been repeating the Send-Mail command with the different attachment paths for each recipient however the problem I am running into since I also have to use -UseSsl -credential I have to authenticate each time a new message is sent. Is there a way to authenticate once without having to do it each time?

Comment: `$creds = Get-Credential`? then you can `Send-MailMessage ... -Credential $creds` Else I don't understand the question

Comment: Here is what I am doing: Send-Mailmessage -To user1@domain -From sender@domain -Subject "Report" -Body "Summary" -attachment "path of file" -smtpserver mail.mail.com -UseSsl -credential "mycredential;Send-Mailmessage -To user2@domain -From sender@domain -Subject "Report" -Body "Summary" -attachment "second path of file" -smtpserver mail.mail.com -UseSsl -credential "mycredential          Each time the Send-MailMessage runs I have to enter the password

Comment: What is `"mycredential`? Is that a variable you have previously saved. That is not proper code. Please include the _real_ code in the question with an [edit].

Answer (score 1):

Send-MailMessage is a wrapper for .net smtpclient. You can do your custom version of it, for example:

```
$client = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
$client.EnableSsl = $true
$client.Host = "smtp.server.com"
$client.Credentials = $creds

foreach ($r in $recipients) {
$from = "from@mail.com"
$to = $r
$msg = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $from, $to
$msg.Subject = "subject"
$msg.Body = "body"
$msg.Attachments.Add("C:\temp\test.html")

$client.Send($msg)
}
```

Comment: Step 1: (Get-Credential).password | ConvertFrom-SecureString > MailPW.txt
Step 2: $pw = Get-Content .\MailPW.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
Step 3: $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential username@domain.com, $pw

Then I was able to just use the variable $cred to avoid the authentication pop up window.

Comment: So are you getting some error or popup using the code above?

Comment: No this stopped the authentication pop up. The problem has been resolved.